# Windows: how to intercept operations with users/groups?

Tags: windows, winapi

Does Windows have a mechanism for intercepting operations with users/groups such as create/delete, membership change ?

Google and stackoverflow give no answers yet. Reversing into netapi32!NetUserAdd etc gives nothing too.

Comment: Good question, and I hope someone can point out a method for just that. But I'm afraid the closest you can get is some hackery involving monitoring of the user database (e.g. registry SAM key in case of a single system, AD database in case of a domain).

Comment: Intercepting WMI events related to Win32_Account etc appears to be the solution of the problem.

Comment: interesting. You should write that up as an answer to get some upvotes :)

Answer (score 0):

Windows does not provide an interception mechanism that provides that feature, but you could hook the [appropriate Win32 APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370649%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) using [Detours](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/) or any other framework (or your own implementation). Once intercepted, you can filter and or forward the functions according to your needs.

Comment: @0xC0000022L: what do you mean by this?

Comment: just that the OP asked for a method provided by Windows itself ... since the OP is obviously capable of RCE, there is no point in mentioning other strategies that side-step the question :)

Comment: @0xC0000022L: this is not a reason to downvote my correct answer!

Comment: Two things: 1. your answer side-steps the question to me this normally means it is off-topic w.r.t. the question, 2. on second thought I agree your wording is sound. However, I cannot take it back without the answer being edited. Do that and I can take back the downvote.

Answer (score 0):

Just some VBScript code for intercepting user creation. It's on you to rewrite it on C++/C#/whatever.

```
sub set_intercept()
    set wmi = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
    set sink = WScript.CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemSink", "SINK_")
    wmi.ExecNotificationQueryAsync sink, "SELECT * FROM __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 1 WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Account'"
end sub 

sub SINK_OnObjectReady(obj, context)
    WScript.Echo "User was created"
end sub

set_intercept()
```